# Getting text from a textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get username and password from the textfield. This is the HTML code:

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-left">
<input type="text" class="span2">
 <input type="text" class="span2">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How can I get this username & password in the LoginController to check for authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to add a `name` property to your input fields. Then specify the `action` and `method` attributes for the `form`. The form would look like this then:

```
<form action="your_route_goes_here" method="post" class="navbar-form pull-left">
<input name="username" type="text" class="span2">
 <input name="password" type="password" class="span2">
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In your LoginController, you can then access the username and password like so, respectively:

```
params[:username]
params[:password]
```